# Jquery get highlighted text in Redactor text editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, text-editor, redactor

I'm using a fantastic jquery text editor named [Redactor](http://redactorjs.com/docs/examples/). I'm trying to add a new button which when clicked gets the text that was highlighted in the text editor.

The script allows to add a new button by adding the following setting:

```
buttonsCustom: {
        button1: {
            title: 'Button', 
            callback: testButton //executes callback on button click
        } 
}
```

then in the callback I want to get the highlighted text

```
function testButton(obj, event, key)
{
     alert(highlighted_text);
}
```

I thoroughly looked in the documentation and there's no way to get highlighted text. I tried other functions like...

```
function getSelText() {
  var txt = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  return txt;
}
```

...but the text editor script already has a way to do it and would be best to use that.

In the script I found where the text selection function is on line 1719 but can't figure out how to use it for a custom button.

Anyone experienced with Redactor, please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick your poison (both methods work on Firefox and IE):

**Method 1: Undocumented internal function**

There is an internal function named `getSelection`, but it isn't part of the public API.

You can call it with `$('#redactor_content').data('redactor').getSelection()`.

**Method 2: Duplicating functionality**

Now if you don't want to rely on accessing the internals of Redactor, you can duplicate the implementation into your own function, replacing access to internal variables with a call to `getDoc()`:

```
function getRedactorSelection(elem)
{
    var doc = elem.getDoc().get(0);
    if (doc.getSelection)
    {
        return doc.getSelection();
    }
    else if (doc.selection)
    {
        return doc.selection.createRange();
    }
};
```

Usage: `getRedactorSelection($('#redactor_content'))`

The upside is that you are protected from changes in how internal functions of Redactor are named and called, but the downside is that your code is no longer browser-independent.

Comment: Brilliant! Method one works but in explorer returns `[object]`

Comment: On IE the selection is a [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you have to call `.text` to get a string. Which does make the method less appealing...

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Redactor added a new function to get selected html.

`$('#redactor').getSelected();`

Answer (score 3):

You probably need this: `$('#redactor_content').getDoc()[0].getSelection();`

Try this:

- Go to: http://redactorjs.com/docs/examples/fixed/ ,
- select some text
- in Firefox (or Chrome) open console and type:

  `alert($('#redactor_content').getDoc()[0].getSelection())`
- press Enter or click run.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work except on Explorer (no surprise..).